# Is there a way to use texture packs in Minecraft PE or ps4-Xbox?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

Is there anyway you can get texture packs in Minecraft PE or ps4-Xbox? I play a lot of regular Minecraft and use texture packs a lot, but I was wondering if you can use texture packs in PE or ps4-Xbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be some downloadable aps that allow you to add textures in the Minecraft PE.
Some sites will allow you to download texture packs: http://mcpeuniverse.com/texture-packs/ 
There are few videos out there showing how to do this, but here is a link to a video for all I-Devices

If you are running on android this video will show you how:

If you are running a JTAG x-box this video will help you:

A little work will be involved to do exactly what you need, but this should get you what you need for these devices.